# jquery datetime picker set minDate dynamic

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, mindate

I guys i'm using a datetimepicker by trentrichardson.com.

I have a form with two input fields : **from** and **to** and i want to be able to set dynamically a minDate to my "to" field  equal to the value of my "from" field.

I know i should use a beforShow option but don't know how to implement the function.

```
$('.from,.to').datetimepicker({

    beforeShow: customRange

});
```

**EDITED/SOLUTION**

```
function customRange(input) {   
if (input.id == 'to') {     
var x=$('#from').datepicker("getDate");
$( ".to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",x ); 
} 
else if (input.id == 'from') {     
var x=$('#to').datepicker("getDate");
$( ".from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",x ); 
} }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can set and get minDate dynamically with setter and getter:

```
//getter
var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

[explained here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: i need that the input field "to" is at least equal of any date value inside "from" field

Answer (score 20):

If you have two textboxes with corresponding IDs `from` and `to` and you want the `minDate` of `to` to be the selected date of `from` then do the following:

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    minDate: 0, // to disable past dates (skip if not needed)
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        // Set the minDate of 'to' as the selectedDate of 'from'
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});

$("#to").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [restrict the datepicker range](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max).

But you want to set this range on creation of the datepicker on the "from". I **[made you a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lat6q/1/)** which seems to work OK as far as I understand the question.

Comment: Hi@andyb, thanks for your code. But after selecting the "from" and "to" date once,then come back to re-select again "from" date". Then the "to" date cannot update according to newly selected "from" date. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Elena I do not see this issue with the demo. After setting both dates, then changing the "from" to be further in the past or to after the "to" then the opening the "to" date selector shows more dates in the past or it is set to the "from" date. Can you elaborate on the problem or if you can create a demo, then maybe ask a new question?

Comment: hi, in your demo it works perfectly. But when I inserted these lines into my jquery month picker ("to" date select part). Then it occurs problem as I described in first part. Please see I posted the code in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411152/django-jquery-month-picker-the-to-date-not-always-updated-as-later-than-from.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

luca: A small addition to your answer...

Using the function you suggested the time component is ignored the first time the datetimepicker is displayed. If you close the datetimepicker and reopen it again, the time component mysteriously reappears. I'm not quite sure what is causing this, but it can be fixed with a bit of a hack:

```
function setMinMaxDate ( element )
{
    // Store current date - setting max/min date seems to destroy time component
    var val = $(element).val();

    if (element.id == 'endDate') 
    {     
        var x=$('#startDate').datetimepicker("getDate");
        $( element ).datetimepicker( "option", "minDate",x ); 
    } 
    else if (element.id == 'startDate') 
    {     
        var x=$('#endDate').datetimepicker("getDate");
        $( element ).datetimepicker( "option", "maxDate",x ); 
    }

    // Restore date
    $(element).val(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use latest version of bootstrap.min.js

```
$("#from").datepicker( {
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true,
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    
        var oldDate = $('.datepicker-current').val();
    
        $('#to').data('datepicker').setEndDate(oldDate);
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers helped me at all. It either didn't work or gave some kind of error.

So I merged them all together and made my own one. I used moment.js as mentioned above, just download it and include it in your page.

```
$("#start_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:00:00',
    onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input){
        var dt2 = $('#end_date');
        var minDate = $('#start_date').val();
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var targetDate = moment(minDate).toDate();
        var dateDifference = currentDate - targetDate;
        var minLimitDate = moment(dateDifference).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        var endDate = moment(dt2.val()).toDate();
        if((currentDate - endDate) >= (currentDate - targetDate))
            dt2.datetimepicker({
                'value': minDate
            });
        dt2.datetimepicker({
            'minDate': '-'+minLimitDate
        });
    }
});
$("#end_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-m-d H:00:00'
});
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this but I couldn't find it. So I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: your solution should be in the top to help others.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery UI `datepicker` there is many Functions which are helpful to set `minDate` or `maxDate` dynamically like `onSelect`, `onClose`.

demo of `onClose` is already provided in @Tanvir's answer see here: [datepicker onClose example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20010398/7719176)

So i will give you example of `onSelect`.

before it i will tell you difference between `onSelect` and `onclose`, as Name suggests `onSelect` fire just after user selects a date and `onClose` fire when datepicker closes after date selection, that's all.

here we have two datepicker `pickupdate1` and `pickupdate2`, and we want to set **selected date of `pickupdate1` to be minDate of `pickupdate2`** and it **should be dynamic**, so here's the code:

```
$("#pickupdate1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {                                           
         $('#pickupdate2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#pickupdate2").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) on trentrichardson.com. They are using "onSelect". For me it's not working perfert. When setting minDate or MaxDate the time component is set to 0 and only the date remains. And I had to solve some localization problems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<input type="date" name="cname" value=""  min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>"/>
```