# How to set mindate dynamically in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

> I am trying to add datetimepicker using jquery datetimepicker.When clicking, datetimepicker is visible.but i cant set mindate dynamically. my html code is

```
 <input id="pickup_date" type="text" readonly="" >
```

> and jquery is

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pickup_date').datetimepicker({                
            controlType: 'select',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',

        });
    $('#pickup_date').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date('01-jun-15'));

    });
```

How to do this.

Comment: Try using valid value to pass to new Date()

Comment: i have already used new Date() but..result is same

Comment: No, the date string shown in question is invalid. Might get better help by posting link to plugin docs

Comment: Pretty much the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375373/jquery-datetime-picker-set-mindate-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

First, I would try with this format for the date:

```
new Date('01/Jun/2015')
```

Second, this syntax for .datetimepicker seems to be working on my system:

```
$("#pickup_date").datepicker({ minDate: (new Date('01/Jun/2015')) })
```

I hope this helps.