# Javascript/Jquery-UI make reusable function that checks if dateTo is after dateFrom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 datepickers. `#datepicker0` and `#datepicker1` and the following code to check if the date_from is after date_to:

```js
$('#datepicker0').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

var valeDate = {
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: function() {
    if ($('#datepicker0').val() > $(this).val()) {
      alert("Date problem");
      $(this).val(null)

    }

    $(this).change();
  }
}

$("#datepicker1").datepicker(valeDate).on("change", function() {
  display("Change event");
```

I would like to remove the parameter `#datepicker0` from the onSelect function in order to make the function reusable.

Could anyone show me how to make it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Convert the dates into timestamps and check wether the number is greater than the other.

Comment: If the value of date2 cannot be before date1, update the `minDate` of `date2` when `date1` has a value set. Then you don't need to validate anything client-side. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375373/jquery-datetime-picker-set-mindate-dynamic) for more information

Comment: no sorry...the function posted is working fine....i would remove from it the dependency by the element "datepicker0".

Comment: More specifically i would like to improve my code from "if ($('#datepicker0').val() > $(this).val()) " to " if ($(generic_value).val() > $(this).val()) "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i used this code:

```
function datepickerValidator(startDate,endDate) {
   var datepickerFrom = startDate;
   var datepickerTo   = endDate;

// returns the millisecond obtained from the string 'dd-mm-yy'
   function getTimeMillis(dateString) {
      var splittedFrom = dateString.split("-");
      var day = splittedFrom[0];
      var month = splittedFrom[1];
      var year = splittedFrom[2];
      var dateTmp = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
      var timeMillis = dateTmp.getTime();
    return timeMillis;
}

var validateDatePickerOption = {dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function() {
            from = getTimeMillis(datepickerFrom.val());
            to = getTimeMillis($(datepickerTo).val());
            if ( from > to )  {
                alert("Date problem: value 'To' must be after 'From'");
                $(this).val(null)
                }
            }
        }
 return validateDatePickerOption;
}
```

and for each datepicker:

```
var from = $("#From");
var to = $("#To");
var datepickerOption = datepickerValidator(from,to);
from.datepicker(datepickerOption);
to.datepicker(datepickerOption);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateDate(datepicker, value) {
   if (value > datepicker.val()) {
       alert("Date problem")
       datepicker.val(null)
   }
   datepicker.change()
}

var valeDate = {
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  onSelect: function() {
      validateDate($(this), $('#datepicker0').val())
  }
}
```

**Next time**, please address questions like this (everything works but code require modifications) to code review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)